# How to change where ImageIO is getting files from?

Tags: java, awt, embedded-resource, javax.imageio

I am making a chess program, which displays the pieces with images. I am loading them with ImageIO like this:

```
    URL resource = Main.class.getResource("/rookWhite.png");
    image = ImageIO.read(resource);
```

That is in a try catch loop, and it works when resources are next to the java folder in src/main, but i can't figure out how to change the location of where it is getting the images from. This isn't a problem until I try to make a jar file from it, because everyone (on stackOverflow) is saying that i need a resources folder next to src to make a jar file. Yes, I have marked my resources folder as resource root.

Comment: Do you use a build tool like maven or gradle? Are your resources located in `src/main/resources`?

Comment: Resource loading works more reliable when not working with URL and Path. Instead directly open an InputStream using `getResourceAsStream`. ImageIO can also directly read from InputStream.

Comment: The way resources get "embedded" differ for each IDE ... and build system.  So, for example, Netbeans Ant Project will "embed" any image (or other resource) that is in the `src` directory, this allows you to have sub folders in `src` directory for your assets. Maven on the other hand, is another story. Sooo, the question is, what IDE and build system are you using

Comment: I am using gradle

Comment: when resources are located in src/main/resources it works, but they need to be in ProjectName/resources

Comment: I am using IntelliJ.

Comment: I tried using an inputstream insted of a URL but again, it only works in IntelliJ, and not in a jar file. I saw that a lot of other people have had similar issues but nothing they did fixed it for me.

Comment: Have a look at this search about [embedded resource questions related to IntelliJ which were marked as solved](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bintellij-idea%5D+%5Bembedded-resource%5D+hasaccepted%3Ayes).

Comment: You do not *need* a `resources` folder (it's just good practice). What matters, is that your IDE/build tool copies the resources into your applications run time class path (either on disk or inside a JAR file), and that the resource path is correct, relative to the root of the class path. If you are using a non-standard directory layout for your IDE/build tool, you will need extra configuration.